# Why does my website automaticly redirects to domain.com instead of www.domain.com

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have no htaccess other then the one that was in the wordpress package.

-If I type www.domain.com, it redirects to domain.com

-If I type domain.com, it redirects to www.domain.com and then redirects another time to domain.com

Can someone explain this weird behavior? Thank you!

The htaccess from the Wordpress package:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What is in the `.htaccess` that was included in your wordpress package? What is in `httpd.conf`?

Comment: That doesn't redirect the client (no `[R]` flag). It's either in `httpd.conf` or a setting in wordpress itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is done by wordpress not .htaccess Go to your wordpress DB and look for the table wp_options. Within it would be an option called siteurl & home change those to http://www.domain.com

Now you will be redirected as you wish

Hope it helps

Comment: siteurl is at domain.com and home at domain.com/wordpress because my wordpress is in a lower directory. I do not necessarily want to always get redirected to www.domain.com, I am mostly wondering why domain.com redirects to www.domain.com, then back to domain.com

Comment: the back to domain.com is because of wordpress since it changes siteurl. The initial www.domain.com maybe due to .htaccess or some default configuration in your server (like httpd.conf) etc, are you using any other frameworks in your default that might be do it too?

Comment: No, just a standard wordpress installation. I'm gonna go look in my server config and maybe some hidden htaccess files. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To access domain with www chage your setting from wp-admin.

Steps: 
1) Go to the setting page
2) Select general setting
3) Now add www in "WordPress Address(URL)" or Site Address (URL). setting

Answer (score 0):

I think Please Check your Permalinks or from Settings=>General Settings=> Site Address (URL).

Thanks
Anand